# python, matplotlib, how to plot only part of a curve

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a curve on a certain place in a graph, now I want only part of this curve to show.
Only the part where x < 0
so it should show the part of the curve that is left of the zero point on the x axis.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
xlim(-36, 23)
ylim(-33, 1033)
plt.title('Sucker Curve')
plt.grid()

x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100)
y = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100)
plt.xlabel('profit / loss in percent of avgcost')
plt.plot(x, y, alpha=0.0)

# should be visible till x = 0
ylb = 0.36 * x**2  # loss buy
plt.plot(x + 12.33, ylb + 196, color='blue', label='loss buy curve')

# should be visible starting from x = 0
yps = (- 0.4739 * x**2)  # profit sell curve
plt.plot(x- 6.66, yps + 273, color='red', label='profit buy curve')

plt.ylabel('percent of settings.MAX_POSITION')
plt.legend()
show()
```

I tried

```
ylb = 0.36 * x**2  # loss buy
plt.plot(x[x < 0] + 12.33, ylb[x < 0] + 196, color='blue', label='loss buy curve')
```

but it is not sharp on the x axis zero  . .

Comment: I need the whole figure as I also have curves that should show starting at the x axis zero . .

Comment: I think you're also limiting the size of the graph, I need tho show the whole graph but only part of the line . .

Comment: `xlb = np.linspace(-50,0,100)` with `ylb = 0.36 * xlb**2` and `plt.plot(xlb + 12.33, ylb + 196)` and also xps = `np.linspace(0,50,100)` with `yps = (- 0.4739 * xps**2)` and `plt.plot(xps- 6.66, yps + 273)`?   Maybe you could make an image to further clarify what you need?

Comment: i need a graph of specific x axis and y axis, then I draw a curve on it but only show part of that curve. still haven't got it sharp.